# Can a Ubuntu live usb be infected with spyware/ virus?

Tags: linux, spyware

I have a Ubuntu 13.10 live usb. I gave it to somebody so that he can install ubuntu. Now I have received it back. I was wondering if it is possible to infect a live usb with spyware or virus ? If yes, how to detect it ?

Answer (score 2):

Of course it can. I presume you didn't make your USB stick irreversibly read-only in hardware (can be done, but it's rather fiddly, and in case of using the read-only switch, it can of course be easily moved back in write position, if your drive even has one), so what you got back on your stick could be anything, unless you check that the complete contents of your drive match the ones you gave away.

The easiest way out is probably by formatting the drive and reloading it with a new copy that you hold and nobody could tamper with, or downloading it again from a trusted source. Alternatively, you could [calculate checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum#Checksum_tools) of all the files on the drive, and compare them and the rest of file metadata (like timestamps) with those you calculated and noted previously, or the ones you find online where you downloaded the files from, to check for evidence of them being tampered with.

Comment: how to do checksum of live usb ?

Comment: Simplest would be calculating checksum of the entire image of your drive (extract it into a new image if you have to) and then comparing it to the checksum of the downloadable ISO image. See the link in the answer for tools you can use to do that.

Comment: are you sure the checksum of iso created from usb will be same as that of the orifinal iso file used to make live usb ? i mean should this be expected in case of no tampering ?

Comment: If the image wasn't [mounted in write mode](http://askubuntu.com/q/54613/126388) (and why would it, if all it was used for was to boot from it?), then yes, they should be the same.

Comment: i think creating iso image will copy all the bits, so checksum will depend on the size of the usb, so how can it be same ?

Comment: If you make an image of the bootable partition, and it was never written on after you mounted a downloadable image onto it, then they will be, tit for tat, the exact same image files. If they're not (to which a change in their checksums should alert you), then your _live_ image was written on / tampered with.

Comment: suppose i make 2 liveusb for ubuntu 13.10, one is of 4 gb and other 8 gb. then i create iso from both the usb. both these iso will have different checksum and also different from original iso. i think u need to recheck your suggestion.

Comment: I think you need to recheck your definitions. What I'm talking about is images of a partition, and what you're talking about is a shadow copy of an entire drive. NOT the same thing! And if what you suggested was true, then each and every ISO image of a DVD  on the internet would have been the size of a DVD's total capacity. And they're clearly not. ;)

Comment: my usb is `/dev/sdb` , it has only one partition which is `/dev/sdb1`. i have created iso from both and both iso are of approx 4 gb. However, iso generated using `sdb1` is slightly smaller than the other.

Comment: this is the code used to create iso `sudo cat /dev/sdb1 > /home/user/test.iso` kindly tell me what wrong i am doing ?

Comment: [Read this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19446/make-a-drive-image-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/) or [this at the Creating Disc Images Using dd section](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DriveImaging)

Comment: well ` dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=/home/testd.iso` also gives a 4 gb iso with different checksum

Comment: OK look, I don't know what you need to match it to, it's not like you said that anywhere. If you're using a downloadable ISO image then chances are it's compressed (see [partimage here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DriveImaging)), but even then, you could simply mount it, calc checksum for it, and then do the same for your USB volume. But this is now a lengthy discussion over what should be a new question on [ubuntu.se] or [su]. The theory is simple enough, find a way to match it tit for tat, the rest is then a bit of Googling.

Answer (score 0):

#### Two questions:

1. Yes, it is possible
2. To **detect** it, one of simplier way is to compare whole content with another USB live stick, holding same version.

Checksums are present on top level of standard Live (debian based) distros. So you could compare this files on both fresh key and the one you got back. Than you could use this file to check whole directories.

#### Detailed explanation:

As this question stand for **`Ubuntu 13.10`**, I've downloaded this version (32bits, for more portability on usb key, but I think 64bit version will present approx same filesystem architecture.) on my desktop. (I prefer ***Debian GNU/Linux***, but it's not the matter).

Well, now:

```
$ sudo mount -o loop,ro Download/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso /media/cdrom
$ cd /media/cdrom
$ ls -ltr
total 2538
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 2560216 Oct 15 14:51 wubi.exe
-r--r--r-- 1 root root     134 Oct 16 21:14 autorun.inf
lr-xr-xr-x 1 root root       1 Oct 16 21:16 ubuntu -> .
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root    2048 Oct 16 21:16 preseed
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root    2048 Oct 16 21:16 pool
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root    2048 Oct 16 21:16 pics
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root    2048 Oct 16 21:16 dists
-r--r--r-- 1 root root     227 Oct 16 21:16 README.diskdefines
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root    2048 Oct 16 21:16 casper
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root   18432 Oct 16 21:16 isolinux
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root    2048 Oct 16 21:16 install
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root    2048 Oct 16 21:16 boot
-r--r--r-- 1 root root    3653 Oct 16 21:16 md5sum.txt
```

There is a file named **`md5sum.txt`** dated on ***October 16***.

This file could not differ between two different key holding *same ISO* (*ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386* => 32bits) !!

```
$ md5sum md5sum.txt 
5765805c23215de23f7775d84a79e140  md5sum.txt
```

This is the md5 sum of this file. **Have to be the same** on each *burned* usb key!

If this match, you could simply make **the** verification:

```
$ md5sum -c < md5sum.txt && echo All OK.
./pics/red-upperleft.png: OK
./pics/red-lowerleft.png: OK
...
./install/README.sbm: OK
All OK.
```

Message `All OK.` are displayed only if `md5sum` end without error.

Comment: how to do checksum ? iso created from usb will be of different size and hence different vchecksum

Comment: If checksums differ, ***detection*** is done: The two keys are not same! :-/ From there, you could try to search for differences and try to explain what/why ( maybe who ;)

Comment: if u burn same iso to two different usb of different sizes and then do the checksum on the 2 usb , u will get different checksum

Comment: @user2917687 Yes! But you may have to check files, not whole partition! (depending on how iso are copied to usb, partition may present same checksums too)

Comment: @user2917687 have a look at my edit.

Comment: could you please explain `$ md5sum -c < md5sum.txt && echo All OK.`

Comment: Is it possible to recreate original iso from the live usb as it has all the files ? THis will make it easier to compare all types of checksum md5/sha1/sha256

Comment: Once you `cd` (change dir) to the root of your mounted usb. `md5sum <md5sum.txt` take the content of file `md5sum.txt` and check **each** file. At end, md5sum return *result code* `$?==0` if **all files** was checked **without** corruption. So with `&&` the command `echo` will be run only if previous command return RC=0.

Comment: @aks No, yes, but no: You could effectively re-create same iso, meaning same behaviours, but it's a little complicated because of boot-image syntax. And even, you're new iso will retain meta informations like creation date, ensuring md5sum **won't** match. The right solution is to compare `md5sum.txt` on both keys **and** run `md5sum -c  <md5sum.txt` from usbkey root path (in `md5sum.txt` path are *relative*).

Comment: @ask if your original iso is `ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386`, the md5sum of this file **must be** `5765805c23215de23f7775d84a79e140`

Comment: md5 does not include metadata http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869880/when-i-hash-a-file-with-md5-what-is-hashed

Comment: so i ask again, is it possible to recreate original iso from live usb ? if not, why ?

Comment: Already answered: Yes it is possible, but no you could not verify md5 from a re-created iso. Why is already explained too! Working around `md5sum.txt` as (already) explained is **the** right way. And no: `md5sum.txt` don't hold meta datas, you could simply read it by using `more` or `less`.

Comment: i think u got me wrong. md5 sum does not take into account the meta data, it only considers the content of the file. so we shud be able to recreate original iso ?

Comment: @aks *md5* and *iso* is independant. *md5* are made **for** that kind of verification. *iso* is a read-only filesystem holding a lot of meta information like *owner*, *date of creation*, *ECC methods* and so on. You may come in pain if you try to build an iso that match **byte per byte** the original iso (even if you know the tool and the syntax previously used to build them.). But anyway you could do has you think... Let my know in case of success!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13530/discussion-between-aks-and-f-hauri)

Comment: is there a way to check the metadata contained in iso ?